# Roles not being assigned from stored procedure in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my ASP.NET app, I am using a stored procedure to get roles to be able to login. Well, I am told that my reader has no data in it. So something is going on and I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

C# Code

```
string userName = GetUsername(txtUserName.Text);
IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
string roles = string.Empty;

var conn = @"Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Web].Get_User_Roles"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", domainName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25);
        cmd.Parameters["@userName"].Value = userName;

        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        List<string> Roles = new List<string>();
        Roles.Add("Administrator,Manager,User");
        roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my `web.config` file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" path="/" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="30" ></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow roles="Administrator, Manager,User"/>
      <allow users="*"/> <!-- might haft to delete this to work, which is ok. Better to have and not need then to need and not have. -->
    </authorization>
```

My **Result** would be that it makes the connection to the database, uses my Username and checks the StoredProcedure to make sure I'm allowed to login and lets me login. I was told that the `reader.Read` isn't holding any data, so therefor it's not picking up if the user is an admin or not. Not really sure what's wrong from here.

Comment: You sure your dB has data in it? Is SP returning something if you call it with same input on management studio? Also, I have some doubts about last few lines of your code :/

Comment: It definately has data in it as we ran it to make sure. I took out the List-Roles lines of code and was still able to login. So it's not picking up my roles at all